# flexisym incompatible with AMS classes since last expl3 update

Tags: latex3, amsart, breqn

It seems that since the last `expl3` update (March 14, 2013), the `flexisym` package (used by `breqn`) is no longer compatible with the AMS document classes.  Here is a minimal failing example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

This gives two `Undefined control sequence` errors at `\begin{document}`.  Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: The fix should be on its way to the archives; meanwhile you can apply the fix suggested [in this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102800/4427)

Comment: This is a 'known issue' and the code has already been updated on CTAN: should appear in TeX Live/MiKTeX in the next day or so.

Comment: Okay, it works now, with the updated `flexisym` v0.97c, dated March 16, 2013, on MiKTeX since March 18.